# Calling convention mismatch for x64 floating point functions

Tags: c++, assembly, 64-bit, calling-convention, tcc

I'm having a weird error. I have one module compiled by one compiler (msvc in this case), that calls code loaded from another module compiled by a seperate compiler (TCC).

The tcc code provides a callback function that for both modules are defined like this:

```
typedef float( * ScaleFunc)(float value, float _min, float _max);
```

The MSVC code calls the code like this:

```
    finalValue = extScale(val, _min, _max);
000007FEECAFCF52  mov         rax,qword ptr [this]  
000007FEECAFCF5A  movss       xmm2,dword ptr [rax+0D0h]  
000007FEECAFCF62  mov         rax,qword ptr [this]  
000007FEECAFCF6A  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [rax+0CCh]  
000007FEECAFCF72  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [val]  
000007FEECAFCF78  mov         rax,qword ptr [this]  
000007FEECAFCF80  call        qword ptr [rax+0B8h]  
000007FEECAFCF86  movss       dword ptr [finalValue],xmm0
```

and the function compiled by TCC looks like this:

```
    float linear_scale(float value, float _min, float _max) 
    { 
        return value * (_max - _min) + _min;
    }
0000000000503DC4  push        rbp  
0000000000503DC5  mov         rbp,rsp  
0000000000503DC8  sub         rsp,0  
0000000000503DCF  mov         qword ptr [rbp+10h],rcx  
0000000000503DD3  mov         qword ptr [rbp+18h],rdx  
0000000000503DD7  mov         qword ptr [rbp+20h],r8  
0000000000503DDB  movd        xmm0,dword ptr [rbp+20h]  
0000000000503DE0  subss       xmm0,dword ptr [rbp+18h]  
0000000000503DE5  movq        xmm1,xmm0  
0000000000503DE9  movd        xmm0,dword ptr [rbp+10h]  
0000000000503DEE  mulss       xmm0,xmm1  
0000000000503DF2  addss       xmm0,dword ptr [rbp+18h]  
0000000000503DF7  jmp         0000000000503DFC  
0000000000503DFC  leave  
0000000000503DFD  ret
```

It seems that TCC expects the arguments *in the integer registers r6 to r8*, while msvc puts them in the sse registers. I thought that x64 (on windows) defines one common calling convention? What exactly is going on here, and how can i enforce the same model on both platforms?

The same code works correctly in 32-bit mode. Weirdly enough, on OSX (where the other code is compiled by llvm) it works in both modes (32 and 64-bit). Ill see if i can fetch some assembly from there, later.

---- edit ----

I have created a working solution. It is however, without doubt, the dirtiest hack i've ever made (bar questionable inline assembly, unfortunately it isn't available on msvc 64-bit :)).

```
// passes first three floating point arguments in r6 to r8
template<typename sseType>
    sseType TCCAssemblyHelper(ScaleFunc cb, sseType val, sseType _min, sseType _max)
    {
        sseType xmm0(val), xmm1(_min), xmm2(_max);
        long long rcx, rdx, r8;
        rcx = *(long long*)&xmm0;
        rdx = *(long long*)&xmm1;
        r8 = *(long long*)&xmm2;

        typedef float(*interMedFunc)(long long rcx, long long rdx, long long r8);

        interMedFunc helperFunc = reinterpret_cast<interMedFunc>(cb);
        return helperFunc(rcx, rdx, r8);
    }
```

Comment: The `TCC` code expects the floats in the registers that are used for integers, not the stack. It's storing them on the stack.

Comment: @Jester you're right, i totally missed that. Mixed up destination operands reading the assembly, ill edit it.

Comment: @HansPassant Hm yes, that seems to be how msvc calls the code, I have never seen the TCC one (passing floating point arguments in integer registers)

Comment: It isn't actually, this isn't __vectorcall.  Sure, there once was just one calling convention in x64, no distinction anymore between cdecl, stdcall, fastcall.  But compiler writers didn't agree on the one remaining one.  TCC is very incompatible here, even GCC passes through XMM.  You could only file a bug report with the project.  Use the [mailing list](https://lists.nongnu.org/mailman/listinfo/tinycc-devel).

Comment: Hmm, I'll look at it. Weirdly enough (as updated in the topic), on OSX it works in both 32 and 64 bit.